# Running Xubuntu without panels

Tags: xubuntu, xfce-panel

I'm running Xubuntu with AWN and I would like to turn off all the XFCE panels, but it does not allow me to do so with the last one. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In /etc/xdg/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-session.xml

Just comment the `xfce-panel` section.

Answer (score 3):

Pending a better option, you could just nuke it after it loads. Crunchbang does something like this in `~/.config/xfce4/autostart.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

# ...other autostart things...

if [ "$(pidof xfce4-panel)" ]; then
    killall xfce4-panel &
fi

avant-window-navigator &
```

Yes, it's a hack... But it should work.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using an Xubuntu distribution with xfce 4.8, you should be able to disable it from the Settings Manager.  Click the icon for Panel, and there should be a drop-down list.  Select the panel that corresponds to the panel you want to remove, and click the delete button beside it:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can remove the xfce4-panel from your start up applications. That way, when your system logs you in, xfce4-panel will never be started.

Comment: how exactly can I do that?